# Why is a database represented as a cylinder in architecture drawings?

Tags: architecture, history

I'm a young upstart programmer and I've never actually seen a database. But computers in large part come in boxes, not in cylinders so I was wondering why they are always represented as a cylinder when people show their architecture drawings.

Is there a reason why or is it just tradition to draw them like that?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822650/why-is-a-database-always-represented-with-a-cylinder/2822750).

Comment: A very quick search turned up [this question about why cylinders are used to represent databases on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822650/why-is-a-database-always-represented-with-a-cylinder), [this question about alternatives to using a cylinder to represent databases on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314482/more-compelling-alternative-to-the-cylinder-icon-to-illustrate-a-database-for-en), and [this post in Google Answers about cylinders representing databases](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/365076.html).

Comment: because databases are cylinders

Answer (score 12):

The icon is probably meant to represent an old-school disk pack like this

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7dNt.jpg],

mainly because databases typically reside on a large random-access device like an HDD.

Comment: I like the way the operator is stroking it :)

Answer (score 9):

Although I don't have a specific reference to cite, I took it to represent a hard drive.  Historically, hard drives store data magnetically on round [cylinders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector).  Since databases are all about persistance, hard drives are the mechanism for doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Because their main purpose is to write data to a cylinder (disk).

Comment: I suppose a platter is a very very short cylinder.

Comment: @DanRay - or you have many platters which resemple a cylinder.

Comment: Before there were disks, there was drum storage (or drum memory).

Answer (score 0):

I've always looked at the icon more as a silo than a cylinder: that is, a large high-volume container that can store loads of grain/salt/data.